# Angular 6 qr code reader integration

Tags: angular, qr-code

I tried following libraries to integrate QR code reader into my app:
https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner (angular library)
https://github.com/schmich/instascan (javascript library)

I also tried their demos and it worked great, but when integrating into my app, I could see the `video` tag element, as well as recording icon on the head tab that means browser is using my webcam. However, my page is completely blank without showing any error. Anyone knows the root cause?